# Django dev server works, apache not

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx

i have such url.conf

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^test/', 'ask.views.index'),
    )
```

and view

```
def index(request):
    latest_question = Question.objects.all().order_by('-ask_date')[:20]
    t = loader.get_template('ask/question.html')
    c = Context({
            'latest_question':latest_question,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

If i run django dev server - every think is ok, but if i proxy from apache i have such error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/test/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
The included urlconf askminaev.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

my apache conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mike/askminaev/askminaev/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/mike/askminaev/askminaev>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

if i run sample script using apache it works

Comment: Is your DEBUG setting on for runserver, but off for apache? Also, is that urls.py the only one in the site?

Comment: Nope, apache run with debug too, i find the solution i restart apache, and it works=)