# Django 1.5 index page doesn't show on deployment server (but works on development server)

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I joined the community to ask this question, and I believe I've done my homework of searching the answers where I just can't seem to fix this (hopefully) one problem. Please point me to the right questions if you think otherwise.

I have a Cent OS VPS which I am attempting to host a website using Django 1.5, whilst developing it on my MacBook pro (OS X 10.6) which actually has Django 1.4 installed (Haven't updated it yet -- figured it will suffice to get me started).

I have managed to deploy a test site with the "polls" app working using nginx and gunicorn servers. Except for the fact that the main index page, i.e. pointing the browser to ~my-domain.com/ , gives an error:

"The requested URL / was not found on this server."

but the polls app, i.e. ~my-domain.com/polls/, is working as expected.

Also, when I change the "settings.py" so that DEBUG=TRUE and use the command

```
> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

to run the development server on the deployment machine (VPS), the index page is working. I can also see the index page when I use runserver on my Mac.

My project hierarchy is as follows:

```
+dj_site
|- manage.py
|+dj_site
||-__init__.py
||-settings.py
||-urls.py
||-views.py
||-wsgi.py
|+index
||-__init__.py
||-models.py
||-settings.py
||-urls.py
||-views.py
||-tests.py
||+templates
|||+index
||||-index.html
|+polls
||-__init__.py
||-models.py
||-settings.py
||-urls.py
||-views.py
||-tests.py
||+static
|||+polls
||||-style.css
||+templates
|||+index
||||-index.html
|+proj_static
||-base.css
|+media
||-foo.txt
```

I've put the relevant parts of my code on pastebin to save space here.

[dj_site/settings.py](http://pastebin.com/eiXsQfW9)

dj_site/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Home /
    url(r'^$', include('index.urls', namespace="index")),

    # for Polls app
    url(r'^polls/',include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
)
```

dj_site/index/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from index import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex:/
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    )
```

dj_site/index/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index/index.html"
```

Sorry for the long message, but any pointers to the right direction will be greatly appreciated. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help.

## EDIT

Sorry guys, I fixed the problem.

Looking at suggested link on the right lead me to this:
[Django dev server works, apache not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130675/django-dev-server-works-apache-not?rq=1)

and so I restarted both gunicorn and nginx servers. Gunicorn was running as daemon so I didn't think I needed to restart it -- but this fixed my error.

In case somebody is going through the same situation, the following commands worked for me:

```
> sudo service nginx restart
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
> ps ax | grep gunicorn
17211 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn dj_site.wsgi:application -- bind=127.0.0.1:<port> --daemon
17216 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn dj_site.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:<port> --daemon
17218 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep gunicorn
> kill 17211
> kill 17216
> gunicorn dj_site.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:<port> --daemon
```

So it didn't have much to do with Django set up, but thank you @Ranju I will leave out the doller sign from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py file, change

```
url(r'^$', include('index.urls', namespace="index")),
```

to

```
url(r'^', include('index.urls', namespace="index")),
```

ie, remove the $ symbol.

Comment: thank you for quick reply. I tried this but didn't change anything. What's causing more confusion is that there's no logs for me to trace! nginx's logs are clear -- and I don't think gunicorn leaves any... :(